# confusion to getopt function in c

Tags: c, linux, parsing, command-line

i had written a code with getopt funcition that is followed:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int result;
    opterr=0;
    puts("The following parsed outcome to command-line argments by getopt(-a, -b* or -c*):");
    while((result=getopt(argc, argv, "ab:c::"))!=-1){
        switch(result){
        case ':':
            printf("getopt returns \'%c\'\toptopt=%c\toptarg=%s\toptind=%d\t", result, optopt, optarg, optind);
            break;
        case '?':
            if(optopt=='b')
                fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument attached. optarg=%s\toptind=%d\t", optopt, optarg, optind);
            else if(isprint(optopt))
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option \'%c\'.\toptarg=%s\toptind=%d\t", optopt, optarg, optind);
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character \'%x\'.\toptarg=%s\toptind=%d\t", optopt, optarg, optind);
            break;
        default:
            printf("getopt returns \'%c\'\toptarg=%s\toptind=%d\t", result, optarg, optind);
            break;
        }
        printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", optind, argv[optind]);}

    puts("Here is parsed argument values:");
    for(result=1; result<argc; result++)
        printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", result, argv[result]);
    for(; optind<argc; optind++)
        printf("No-option argument values: argv[%d]=%s\n", optind, argv[optind]);
    return 0;
}
```

then I compile the above program into executable file named `parse`.
Run parse with following command-line argument:

```
./parse -ac b
```

here is output:

```
  The following parsed outcome to command-line argments by getopt:
  getopt returns 'a'      optarg=(null)   optind=1        argv[1]=-ac
  getopt returns 'c'      optarg=(null)   optind=2        argv[2]=b
  Here is parsed argument values:
  argv[1]=-ac
  argv[2]=b
  No-option argument values: argv[2]=b
```

my confusion is why `getopt` could return `c` when it encounter `c` in `argv[1] ac`. because it was not `-c`. in my expectation, it is suppose to execute statement `case '?':`

Comment: Your use of no braces is misleading. Please indent your code properly. Please use an indentation style. Please put separate statements like `break` on separate lines.

Comment: you can combine multiple options in the same argument. `-ac` is the same as `-a -c`.

Comment: but my confusion since -ac is the same as -a -c, why argv[1]=-ac ? and why not argv[1]=-a argv[2]=-c?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `getopt`, single-character options without arguments can be combined with the following option. That's what makes it possible to type

```
ls -lR
```

This works even if the following option takes an argument.

Comment: but my confusion since `-ac` is the same as `-a` `-c`, why `argv[1]=-ac` ? and why not `argv[1]=-a` `argv[2]=-c`?

Comment: @brushmonk: getopt doesn't modify the strings in argv. If argv[1] is `-ac`, that's what it is. What getopt does is parse the entries into individual options, so you see option `a` and then option `c`.

Comment: @brushmonk: Although getopt has an internal variable which tracks where it is in `argv[optind]`, it doesn't export that variable publicly. But you have the option character and the argument, if any, which is really all the information you need.

Comment: why is `c` in `-ac` parsed by getopt successfully? and next `argv` `b` is not parsed by getopt, therefore is the hyphen (`-`) used for parse startup?

Comment: @brushmonk: This is explained well by [man 3 getopt](https://youtu.be/XVqAo5jI5WM) on a Gnu/linux system: "An element of *argv* that starts with '-' (and is not exactly "-" or "--") is an option element.  The characters of this element (aside from the initial '-') are option characters. If **getopt**() is called repeatedly, it returns successively each of the option characters from each of the option elements."

Comment: @brushmonk: So, yes. `getopt` only looks at arguments which start with a `-`, and it allows those arguments to contain multiple options, of which only the last can take an argument.

Comment: from ur answer, i generally know the rule of getopt() function. thank you after all